# how to escape setState in a loop

Tags: reactjs

I'm calling an API and trying to update the state inside a for loop which is not recommended, but I cannot figure out any other way to get this done. Anyone might have any recommendations?

```js
      for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        fetch(`API`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(async (newRecord) => {
          console.log(newRecord)
          if (newRecord.offset !== undefined) {
            this.setState({offset: newRecord.offset})
          } else if (newRecord.offset === undefined) {
            this.setState({offset: ''})
          }
        })
     }
```

Comment: Since these fetches will be finishing at unpredicatable times, what is the desired behavior if they finish in different orders? Your current code will keep the offset of whichever one finishes last, and overrite the rest; is that desired?

Comment: Store your api data in an object or array while looping and then set state after looping.

Comment: @NicholasTower yes

Comment: Ok. It's unusual that you would want to do that, but since you do, I recommend leaving your code the way it is. The reason you'll see recommendations not to set state in a loop is that it can cause you to overwrite the state, and if it's an async operation the overwriting can happen in a random order. For most cases, that's undesirable.

Comment: @NicholasTower the problem is that I want every time each loop runs to update the state, and then loop again.

Comment: Is this accurate: You want it to start one fetch, then wait til it's done, then set state, and only then kick off the second fetch?

Comment: @NicholasTower Correct, and the second fetch needs the updated state from the first fetch.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it appears you need the loop to wait before proceeding. This is easiest if you can use async/await, as in:

```
async function someFunction() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    const response = await fetch(`API`);
    const newRecord = await response.json();
    if (newRecord.offset !== undefined) {
      this.setState({offset: newRecord.offset})
    } else if (newRecord.offset === undefined) {
      this.setState({offset: ''})
    }
}
```

This will overwrite the `offset` part of the state each time through the loop, but that's apparently what you want.

If async/await is not an option, you'll need to create a chain of promises, something like this:

```
let p = Promise.resolve();
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  p = p.then(() => fetch(`API`))
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((newRecord) => {
      if (newRecord.offset !== undefined) {
        this.setState({offset: newRecord.offset})
      } else if (newRecord.offset === undefined) {
        this.setState({offset: ''})
      }
    })
}
```